# Jest: Class mock does not use mockImplementation

Tags: typescript, jestjs, create-react-app

**PropertyBasedCache.ts**

```
export class PropertyBasedCache {
  get(key: string) {
    // return value from cache if any
  }
  
  set(key: string, value: any) {
    // cache value
    return this.get(key) 
  }
}
```

**Transformer.ts**

```
export class Transformer {
  private cache: PropertyBasedCache

  constructor() {
    this.cache = new PropertyBasedCache()
  }

  transform() {
    if(this.cache.get("key")) {
      return this.cache.get("key")
    }
  }
}
```

**SomeTest.test.ts**

```
import { PropertyBasedCache } from "./PropertyBasedCache"
import { Transformer } from "./Transformer.ts"

jest.mock("./PropertyBasedCache", () => ({
  PropertyBasedCache: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    get: jest.fn(),
    set: (_, value) => value
  }))
}))

test("should use cached value on subsequent calls", () => {
  const transformer = new Transformer()

  // ↓ Throws `cache.get` is not a function
  // `console.log(this.cache)` inside of `Transformer` logs `mockConstructor {}`
  transformer.transform()
})
```

I've followed the official docs about mocking non-default class exports: https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#mocking-non-default-class-exports.

I mean shouldn't `mockImplementation` call my custom function once a new instance of **PropertyBasedCache** is created and therefore `get/set` should be defined?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. I see no way how this code can behave like that. The thing you describe sounds like you have resetMocks somewhere, which would be a big mistake. There's a need for `__esModule` property as well https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options but it doesn't seem to affect your setup.

Comment: What happens if you put your jest.mock statement inside a beforeEach block?

Comment: @ShafiqJetha Nothing good. It will lose the ability to affect top-level import this way.

Comment: Yep. What a totally useless suggestion I provided. Thanks for putting me in my place.

Comment: I've tried adding `__esModule` without success. Isn't that only required for ES `default` imports? Here's the repo with the failing test `Transformer.test.ts`: https://github.com/steschwa/jest-mock-demo